# Determinant and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]
In the explanation image, what is the purpose of the determinant det? I don't understand the relationship to the linear equation. Thank you.

Comment: (Non zero vector sent to zero) iff (Non invertible matrix) iff (Determinant zero).

Comment: Do you understand what a determinant is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following equation 
$$(A-\lambda I)v=0,$$
By definition vector $v$ is not equal to zero.
We also know that if $det(A-\lambda I) \neq 0$, therefore columns of matrix $(A-\lambda I)$ are linearly independent and it means that zero can't be represented as a linear combination of this columns with any vector but $v=0$. 
Is it more clear now?